# How this Regex eliminates html?

Tags: java, regex

I saw one code example and didn't understand how this prints only Print statement.
Appreciate your help on this.

```
String str = "<a href=/utility/ReportResult.jsp?reportId=5>Print</a>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""));

OutPut: Print
```

How to modify my regex expression to print Print<>Report instead of PrintReport. Below is my regex and statement.
        String str = "Print<>Report";

```
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<.*?>", ""));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print `Print<>Report` instead of `PrintReport`, change the `*` by `+`:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<.+?>", ""));
//                            here __^
```

`*` means **0** or more precedent character
`+` means **1** or more precedent character

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape the `<` (angular braces). So in java `str.replaceAll("<.*?>", "")` will be sufficient.

How it works :

`<.*?>`  --> Search for first `<` then match everything until the next `>`. Note that `.*?` is called *lazy* selector / matcher.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  How can I modify my regex to print Print<>Report instead of PrintReport. Below is my regex and statement.                   String str = "<a href=/utility/ReportResult.jsp?reportId=5>Print</a><>Report";
  
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<.*?>", ""));

Answer (score 0):

Its a Regex says anything b/w "<" and ">" must be repalce by ""(blank string) 
So

```
<a href=/utility/ReportResult.jsp?reportId=5>==> ""(blank)
</a>==>""(blank)
```

and only "Print" left

Answer (score 0):

First, the leading backslashes are treated as an escape sequence for Java, so the actual regular expression is `\<.*?\>`

The `\<' matches the`<` character (the backslash again is an escape sequence, which indicates that the following character should be interpreted literally and not as a regex operator). This is the beginning of an html tag.

The `.` token matches any character.

The `?` is a reluctant quantifier that indicates that the preceding token (any character in this case) should be matched zero or more times.

The `/>` matches the end of a tag. Because the `?` is reluctant, the `.` does not match the character(s) that can be matched by this token.